# How to draw to a framebuffer with target texture bigger than the screen resolution?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw to a texture, using frame buffer. The texture has size bigger than my window's size. After the drawing, anything that ends up on the outside of the screen is cut off.

I've tried setting the Viewport to fit the texture resolution and disabling the scissor test (It is disabled by default, I don't use anyway). I read somewhere that I may need RenderTarget, but I can't understand why or how to use it without depth or stencil buffer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide more information or picture to illustrate?

Comment: How large is the texture/renderbuffer attached to the FBO?

Comment: I have a few textures that I use for tilemap rendering. I am trying to combine all tiles into one single texture in order to use only one texture when drawing the whole map. So far I do not use renderbuffer. My texture is around 4000x4000 resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my mistake was when displaying the resulting texture, rather then when drawing on it.

Thanks for everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use a framebuffer object for offscreen drawing. You shouldn't use a window based framebuffer for rendering pictures you'd want to reuse (texture, save to file, etc.) anyway, since a window's framebuffer and its contents may become invalid at any time (even in the small space of time between finishing a rendering and calling `glReadPixels`).

Comment: I'm new to opengl so maybe my lingo is wrong. I am generating a framebuffer object for this (using glGenFramebuffers) and I am drawing to that fbo. Still my target texture is cut off. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Moon4u: Do you also set the viewport before rendering to the FBO? Viewports are drawing state. If you have your `glViewport` calls in the windows resize/reshape event handler, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, I do set the viewport before the draw call.

Comment: @Moon4u: Then provide the code that's failing. A proper [mcve].